# Left join (or equivalent) to number index by group

Tags: r

I have a sequence of numbers (days):

```
dayNum <- c(1:10)
```

And I have a dataframe of id, day, and event:

```
id = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "cc") 
day = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 2) 
event = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y")

df = data.frame(id, day, event)
```

Which looks like this:

```
id day event
aa   1 Y
aa   2 Y
aa   3 Y
bb   1 Y
bb   6 Y
cc   2 Y
```

I am trying to put this dataframe into a form that resembles left joining dayNum with df for each id.  That is, even if id "aa" had no event on day 5, I should still get a row for "aa" on day 5 with N/A or something under event.  Like this:

```
id day event
aa   1 Y
aa   2 Y
aa   3 Y
aa   4 N/A
aa   5 N/A
aa   6 N/A
aa   8 N/A
aa   9 N/A
aa   10 N/A
bb   1 Y
bb   2 N/A
bb   3 N/A 
bb   4 N/A 
bb   5 N/A 
bb   6 Y
bb   7 N/A 
           ...etc
```

I can make this work using dplyr and left_join when my dataframe only contains one unique id, but I am stuck trying to make this work with a dataframe that has many different ids.

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `expand.grid` and `merge`.  We create a new dataset using the `unique` 'id' of 'df' and the 'dayNum'.  Then `merge` with the 'df' to get the expected output.

```
merge(expand.grid(id=unique(df$id), day=dayNum), df, all.x=TRUE)
#   id day event
#1  aa   1     Y
#2  aa   2     Y
#3  aa   3     Y
#4  aa   4  <NA>
#5  aa   5  <NA>
#6  aa   6  <NA>
#7  aa   7  <NA>
#8  aa   8  <NA>
#9  aa   9  <NA>
#10 aa  10  <NA>
#11 bb   1     Y
#12 bb   2  <NA>
#13 bb   3  <NA>
#14 bb   4  <NA>
#15 bb   5  <NA>
#16 bb   6     Y
#17 bb   7  <NA>
#18 bb   8  <NA>
#19 bb   9  <NA>
#20 bb  10  <NA>
#21 cc   1  <NA>
#22 cc   2     Y
#23 cc   3  <NA>
#24 cc   4  <NA>
#25 cc   5  <NA>
#26 cc   6  <NA>
#27 cc   7  <NA>
#28 cc   8  <NA>
#29 cc   9  <NA>
#30 cc  10  <NA>
```

A similar option using `data.table` would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df`), set the 'key' columns, join with the dataset derived from cross join of unique 'id' and 'dayNum'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key=c('id', 'day'))[CJ(id=unique(id), day=dayNum)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Akrun, that set me in the right direction and I ultimately figured out a solution.  The expand.grid function is exactly what I needed to know about.  Thank you!

Comment: @user1252489  Glad to know that it helped you.